# SQL Select Distinct Date & ID count

Tags: sql, postgresql

my SQL table is

```
|  date             |  id  |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   1  |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   2  |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   1  |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   3  |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   1  |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   2  |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   3  |
```

I would like to get the output as below

```
|        date       |  id  | count  |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   1  |    1   |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   2  |    1   |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   3  |    0   |
|     03 Aug 2018   |   4  |    0   |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   1  |    0   |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   2  |    0   |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   3  |    1   |
|     04 Aug 2018   |   4  |    0   |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   1  |    1   |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   2  |    1   |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   3  |    1   |
|     05 Aug 2018   |   4  |    0   |
```

Basically, I want to get a distinct date, id and their count if id is not present for a particular date then it shows count as 0.

I have tried the query

```
select date, id, count(id) from table group by date,id;
```

But the output is not giving me the desired outcome. Is there any way to achieve desired output using SQL query?

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT, and it works on the whole selected rows!!! Remove those redundant parentheses to write clearer code, i.e. simply `select distinct date, id, ...`. However, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates here, so there's no need to do select distinct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the existing data.  Presumably, you then want aggregation for the count:

```
select d.date, i.id, count(t.id)
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct id from t) i left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.id = i.id
group by d.date, i.id
order by d.date, i.id;
```

If the count is always 0 or 1, you don't need the aggregation (it makes the query more expensive to run).

```
select d.date, i.id, ( t.id is not null )::int as count
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct id from t) i left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.id = i.id
order by d.date, i.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Gordon Linoff ... What if my date and id are present in the different table and I'm joining both tables by 'value' column then how should I update query mentioned by you above?

Comment: @Haru53 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  But, you can use a CTE (`with` statement) to define the "table" that you want.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Could please tell me what is the “t” table in answer you provided.

Comment: @Haru53 . . . It is shorthand for your table name.